# why i don't have access to id in CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

hi i'm working in visual studio with bootstrap.
i'm trying to design the section at the and of code, but it doesn't work (i don't have the access to id="TikNehesTitle".
  i added my HTML and CSS (in comment) code here.
thanks for responding.

**my HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="he">

<head>
    <title></title>    

        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />
</head>

<body dir="rtl">

    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <!-- menu list-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">הירשם</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">התחבר</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">צור קשר</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">אודות</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">איזור מגורים</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">דף הבית</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </nav>
    </div>

    <section>
        <div class="container" id="TikNehesTitle"><h1>תיק נכס</h1></div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **my CSS:**

body 
{
    
}

TikNehesTitle{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

Comment: You're missing the `#` before `TikNehesTitle` in that comment. I don't know if that's what your issue is.

Answer (score 4):

CSS id is set with `#` prefix.
Simply set your CSS to:

```css
body {

}

#TikNehesTitle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```